# 'No module named flask' in VScode terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, virtualenv

While attempting to create my first flask application, I created a virtual environment and used `pip install Flask` to attempt to install the flask module in the VScode terminal. This appears to have worked successfully.
However, when running this code:

```html
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, request, render_template, session

app = Flask(__name__)
```

I receive the following output from the terminal:
`c:\Users\srija\Desktop\MLProjects\flask_ai\venv\Scripts\python.exe: No module named flask`

I have attempted multiple different methods of installation from similar questions on this site, none of which produce a unique output. I believe that I have conceptual error from my lack of understanding. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does the application launch properly if you attempt to run it __without__ the virtual environment? I mean using your system python instead of the one in the venv?

Comment: @kalatabe Unfortunately not, I receive the same output

Answer (score 0):

Please check where you have installed the flask module through the command of `pip show flask`, make sure you have installed it in the `venv` virtual environment.

Answer (score -2):

Sorry for giving random advice instead of answering your question, but you don't really need to use virtual environments for such simple projects. It overcomplicates things for no reason. Just use your system's (latest) Python/Flask if you don't need a specific version. `venv` is supposed to protect from dependency hell on servers where multiple Python programs with **different hardcoded versions** of dependencies are deployed.

Comment: thank you for you advice nonetheless! I was planning on adding a lot more to this project, but I have paused here due to this error.

Comment: This still applies to other libs that you might add in the future besides Flask. I suggest just using your system python/pip and having fun coding, instead of fiddling with the environment. **If** your environment starts to get messed up, **then** you solve it with `venv`